# Адаптивный поворот текста

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Нужно сделать заголовок адаптивного блока с поворотом. Загвоздка в том, что блок адаптивный, ширина меняется относительно экрана, и высота может быть сколь угодно разная, в зависимости от внутреннего содержания. При повороте нужно учесть на какую ширину и высоту сместится блок при повороте, а она получается разная. Текст съезжает, ведь ширина становится высотой, а высота шириной. Помогите разобраться.

Как сохранить пропорции текста? Добавить еще одну обертку и повернуть в обратную сторону? Возможно ли это только с помощью `css`?

Желаемый результат, заголовок(красным) должен быть расположен по центру, по вертикали и по горизонтали:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода:

```css
.block{
  position:relative;
  padding-left:5rem;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:50%;
}
.pin{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:3rem;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.5);
}
.pin span{
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  text-align:center;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  background:rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.5);
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="pin"><span>Заголовок</span></div>
  
  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используем предназначенный для этих целей `writing-mode: vertical-lr` + `transform: rotate(180deg)`. Центрировать надпись внутри будем при помощи флексбокса.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.pin {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.5);
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  display: flex;
}
.pin span {
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="block">
  <h1 class="pin"><span>Заголовок</span></h1>
  
  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
</section>
```

<sub>edited: поскольку вопрос популярен, а код явно копируют, решил поправить разметку.</sub>

Comment: у меня это ужасно выглядит -- совсем ни как на макете

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ваш баг-репорт не очень-то информативен.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59486/discussion-between---and-kizoso  здесь скрин

Comment: Если у вас Сафари, то это вполне возможно, поскольку `writing-mode` для иос все еще надо писать с префиксом. Однако, как хорошо, что это всего-лишь сниппет и в продакшен люди выливают код после автопрефиксера :-)

Comment: это же обычный win7 .. ie11

Comment: И для ИЕ11 тоже автопрефиксер все поправит.

Comment: мой пример не требует автопрефикс .. почему то

Answer (score 4):

Вот так работает, но только если текст в одну строку, без переносов.

```css
.block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.pin {
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.5);
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 3rem;
}

.pin span {
  bottom: 50%;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -500px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -500px;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: center center 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="pin"><span>Заголовок</span></div>

  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст</p>
  <p class="text">Текст Разный текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Неизвестное количество текста текст</p>
  <p class="text">Сколько угодно текста текст</p>
</div>
```

[Или смотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/qmvvf7fu/)

Comment: Спасибо, ваш пример тоже хорош, отметила предыдущий ответом, т к - ответ был раньше вашего.

Answer (score 0):

Так вроде ... без всяких трудностей

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html,body{
height:100%;
}
.r{
width:50px;
height:100%;
background:#ccc;
text-align:center;
line-height:50px;
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
writing-mode:tb-rl;
 font: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
}
.r span{
display:inline-block;
transform:rotate(-90deg);
font-size:30px;
height:4vh;
color:#fff;
}
@media screen and (max-height:520px){
.r span{
 display:inline-block;
 height:6vh;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="r">
 <span>п</span>
 <span>р</span>
 <span>и</span>
 <span>м</span>
 <span>е</span>
 <span>р</span>
</div>
```

Comment: ваш пример не адаптивный, а фиксированный

Comment: если ваш ответ не будет дублем готового ответа, то давайте. интересно посмотреть

Comment: вы либо невнимательно прочитали задание, либо не понимаете принцип адаптивности, спасибо, но к сожалению ваш ответ как раз не подходит