# Поворот текста вертикально при помощи css

Tags: html, css, html5

Нужно повернуть текст вертикально и расположить справа/слева возле изображения/текста. Реализовал при помощи следующего кода:

```
.vertical_text{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -320px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Возникает проблема, необходимо абсолютно позиционировать этот блок текста по отношению к блоку с изображением и величина смещения зависит от длинны строки текста. Я так понимаю что браузер считает что текст остался в прежнем горизонтальном состоянии и берет отсчет от этого положения. Сама проблема заключается в том что под каждый блок текста приходится добавлять свой стиль со своим горизонтальным смещением чтобы подогнать его к изображению/тексту, пытаюсь найти универсальное решение для всех случаев. Пример на фото:[image: пример]

Comment: [Адаптивный поворот текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672180/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)

Answer (score 4):

```css
p{
   writing-mode: tb-rl;
   transform:rotate(180deg);
   font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<p> lorem ipsum</p>
```

support : http://caniuse.com/#search=writing-mode

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79295/discussion-on-answer-by--------css).